# Category Title on top of webpage for WordPress theme

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, categories

I have a website made in WordPress/WooCommerce using the Woodmart theme.

I would like to ask if it is possible to change the categories page layout. I want to show the titles at the top of the category image, like this:

[image]

At the moment they show at the bottom. This is the actual page: https://klay.com.au/categories-test/

How do I achieve this?

Comment: First I would do is to install AceIDE plugin - it will help you to manipulate the files and edit them. Then let's start by creating a child theme: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/ . After that's done, find the tempate that generates this portion of page (likely called something-something archives or something-something categories) and override it in chid theme, and switching template parts around the way you like. Every theme is a bit different, so you have to do this work for yourself.  Search for  file that contains ```class="wrapp-category"```

Comment: Thank you very much